# Looping through an array to create an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to write a function that takes an array such as:

```
var columns = ['distance', 'times', 'acceleration']
```

Then from this array, I want to generate something like this:

```
[{id: id_0, distance: 0, times: 0, acceleration: 0}, {id: id_1, distance: 1, times: 1, acceleration: 1}]
```

Notice that we have 2 objects here, but I want it to be whatever number I pass in to my parameter. Here is what I have:

```
generateData: function(rows, columns) {
  var generatedData = [];
  for (var i = 0, rowLen = rows.length; i < rowLen; i++) {
    for (var n = 0; i < columns.length; n++) {
      // not sure how to construct an object here from looping through my columns array
      generatedData.push({
      id: 'id_ + n',
      // confused here
      });
    }
  return generatedData;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the perfect place to dynamically create your own function.  Try this:

```
function createArrayOfObjects(columns, count) {
  var objectProps = new Array(columns.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
    //":j" will be the variable j inside the dynamic function
    objectProps[i] = columns[i] + ":j";
  }

  var funcBody = "var arr = new Array(count);" +
      "for(var j = 0; j < count; j++){" +
          "arr[j] = {" + objectProps.join(',') + "};" +
      "}" +
      "return arr;";

  //Create a new function and call it with count as the parameter, returning the results
  return new Function("count", funcBody)(count);
}

var count = 10;
var columns = ['distance', 'times', 'acceleration'];

createArrayOfObjects(columns.concat('id'), count);
```

This has the benefit of only having to loop over the columns array once where other solutions require nested loops.

[JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/dynamic-function-vs-nested-array-object-creation)

Comment: Hm, last time I tested this approach it didn't proof to be a lot faster. It seems to work here, however. +1 for the effort, but I think it's not necessary for OP and he should use the trivial (and short) solution.

Comment: @Bergi, I would argue that this solution(10 lines of code, or 6 depending on how you count the funcBody string) is the same length as the trivial solution (10 lines of code)

Comment: Oh, that's right, I misjudged it from the appearance of your snippet. However, dealing with code strings is still errorprone, e.g. if the `columns` are no valid identifier names your code would fail.

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you away the initial non-optimized solution. Its upto you to do the optimizations.

```
generateData: function(rows, columns) {
  var generatedData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var myObj = {};
      myObj["id_" + i] = i;
      for (var n = 0; n < columns.length; n++) {
          myObj[columns[n]] = i;
      }
      generatedData.push(myObj);
  }
  return generatedData;
}
```

Comment: What optimisations are you talking about?

Comment: @Bergi See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26023990/2464634) for an optimized version.

Answer (score 1):

A functional approach that will take the object properties from the passed in array, instead of hard-coding them, might look something like this inside the for loop to populate an array named 'rows' with property names coming from the values of an array named 'cols':

```
cols.forEach(function(cv, ci, ca) { rows[ri][cv] = ri; });
```

See the snippet for a full example. Note that, in this example, I'm just shoving the current index of "rows" into the object as the property value.

```js
var columns = ['distance', 'times', 'acceleration'];

function generateData(numRows, cols) {
    rows = new Array(numRows);
    for(ri=0; ri < rows.length; ri++) {
        rows[ri] = { id: ri };
        cols.forEach(function(cv, ci, ca) {
            rows[ri][cv] = ri;
        });
    }
    return rows;
}


data = generateData(5, columns);
console.log(data);
```